# c# Builder Compiler in exe

Tags: c#

[Как создать билдер для своей программы](http://zhyk.ru/forum/archive/index.php?t-655932.html)

Ребят хочу уточнить ещё кое какие моменты, начал вроде вникать.
На примере у меня уже есть готовая программа, в ней много классов, я читал что нужно сборку в txt собрать или что там и кинуть в ресурсы!

1 - Как классы запихнуть в txt ?

2 - Если много классов как их собрать вмести, или как быть? ( точнее не пойму, с каждым классом нужно в txt переводить?)

Может у кого-то есть уже готовые реализации, поделитесь...

Comment: Опишите, зачем вы изобретаете велосипед? Не проще ли воспользоваться IDE типа Visual Studio?

Comment: Я учусь создавать билдер для своей программы,и много чего не знаю, расскажите мне про IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Не понимаю смысла в изобретении собственного велосипеда с квадратными колесами...

1. Есть удобные [IDE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8), которые все это умеют, например [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/ru-ru/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)
2. Если есть необходимость компиляции без IDE, то можно воспользоваться консольным [компилятором](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/78f4aasd.aspx), который поставляется вместе с Framework.

Comment: Это не то что нужно, мне нужно чтобы пользователь сам создавал себе билд со своими параметрами, нужно именно от    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188882/compile-and-run-dynamic-code-without-generating-exe

Comment: @ArteS, я могу ошибаться, но консольным компилятором можно этого всего добиться.

Comment: http://headsigned.com/article/csharp-scripting-example-using-csharpcodeprovider    мне нужен от этого пример, чтобы понять, возможно ваш пример может сделать что-то подобное, но я всё таки хочу с чего-то начать!